# How to get the selected value from ionic radio-group

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a radio group in Ionic and when I returned the value selected by this group I get "undefined".

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="myType">
      <ion-radio value="1">Type 1</ion-radio>
      <ion-radio value="2">Type 2</ion-radio>
      <ion-radio value="3">Type 3</ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

and in the controller I try to access the value like this:

```
console.log($scope.myType);  // returnes undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Your console log is from AngularJS 1.X

```
console.log($scope.myType);
```

Angular2 doesn't longer use $scope, try:

```
console.log(this.myType);
```

(After properly declaring public myType in your class)